# Order elements in html Django

Tags: javascript, html, django, element

So I have this elements

```
  {% for chat in content %}
    <a class="clearfix" href="{% if chat.second == request.user %}{{ chat.first }}{% elif chat.second != request.user %}{{ chat.second }}{% endif %}">
      <div class="ProfileImg" style="background-image: url({% if chat.second == request.user %}{{ chat.first.profile.avatar.url }}{% elif chat.second != request.user %}{{ chat.second.profile.avatar.url }}{% endif %})"></div>
      <div class="about">
        <div class="name">{% if chat.second == request.user %}{{ chat.first }}{% elif chat.second != request.user %}{{ chat.second }}{% endif %}</div>
        <input type="hidden" class="number" value="{% if chat.second != request.user %}{{ chat.first_thread_notification }}{% elif chat.second == request.user %}{{ chat.second_thread_notification }}{% endif %}">
        <div class="status">
          {% if chat.second != request.user %}  
            {% if chat.first_thread_notification >= 1 %}{{ chat.first_thread_notification }} msg sin leer <i class="fa fa-circle notification"></i>{% else %}chat activo{% endif %}
          {% elif chat.second == request.user %}
            {% if chat.second_thread_notification >= 1 %}{{ chat.second_thread_notification }} msg sin leer <i class="fa fa-circle notification"></i>{% else %}chat activo{% endif %}
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  {% endfor %}
```

in the input class='number' val there is a value that contain a number, an especific number of each chat.
what I need is to order the elements depending on the value of the number
I try this but that doesnt work

```
  // order the chat values
  $( ".clearfix" ).each(function() {
    var notification_numbers =  $(this).find(".number").val();

    $(this)[0].style.order = notification_numbers
  
 });
```

does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: You need to order the chats? Why can't you order them in your views?

Comment: @leelum1, what do you mean?, I am trying to order it in my frontend, they have diferent random values